# is it possible to put my local pc in a gcloud project domain?

Tags: ssh, google-cloud-platform, tunnel

This might be a really stupid question but I don't know where to begin to search for something like that.

Im using google cloud.

I have a master node in gcloud called master-node and a couple of slave nodes called slave-node-1, slave-node-2. They all have external IP addresses.

I can connecting to the master instance using the following command, `gcloud compute ssh master-node -i /.ssh/sshkey`.

Then, if I want to connect to the other two instances, I could do something like `ssh slave-node-1 -I /.ssh/sshkey`.

I also know its possible to use an ssh tunnel and forward a port so I can do things like connect to 127.0.0.1:5901 on my local pc so I can see the desktop on the vm instance.

My question is... Is possible to put my local computer into the same domain as that vm instance in the gcloud project so that if I did `ssh slave-node-1 -I /.ssh/sshkey` from my local pc, it would work and I could connect to my slave-node-1 instead of using the external IP address; it would be as if I was the master-node in my gcloud project.

Does my question make sense?

Comment: Yes and No. It depends on what you want to do. For you last question, look at `ssh config` https://linuxize.com/post/using-the-ssh-config-file/ and https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/config-ssh